# Valgrind log both xml.log and text.log at the same time

Tags: valgrind

I wanted to log both xml and text output results of valgrind memcheck.
I tried this command .

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --xml=yes --log-file=TextLog.log --xml-file=XMLFile.log test
```

but only xml file was written.text file had no data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using tool option to set it to 'memcheck', since by default valgrind uses 'memcheck' as the tool. Just for your information.
Even there is no issue also, in using tool option.

Try using the below command, to get the logs in both XML file and log file.

```
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=XMLFile.log > Textlog.log 2>&1 test
```

Is this one you are expecting?

more information can be found in below link,

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.basicopts